# Update SQL Server from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

What's the error on this when I run it it's give me this error

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

It's updating by using ID that I take it from a dropdown list.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string constr = "Data Source=YAZAN-PC ; initial Catalog=Elder ; user = sa ; pwd =****;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string sql = "Select * from Users;";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = "0";

        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        ddlID.DataSource = dt;

        ddlID.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlID.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = "Data Source = YAZAN-PC ;" +
                   "initial catalog = Elder;" +
                   "user = sa ; pwd = ****;";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    string Sql =
    "Update Users Set Name=@Name , Gender=@Gender , Email=@Email ,UserType=@UserType, BirthDate=@BirthDate , Password=@Password, RePassword=@RePassword where ID=@ID;";
   con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rblGender.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", rblUserType.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", txtBirthDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePassword", txtRePassword.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

That's the table structure in SQL Server:

```
ID           int           not null primary key identity,
Name         nvarchar(50)  not null ,
Gender       Char(1)       not null ,
Email        nvarchar(50)  not null , 
UserType     char(1)       not null ,
BirthDate    date          not null ,
Password     nvarchar(50)  not null , 
RePassword   nvarchar(50)  not null
```

Comment: It means your trying to put more data in the column than it wiill take (i.e., say it's a VARCHAR(50) and the length of the data is 100.  By the way, please tell us you did **not** post the password for your sa account in your question....

Comment: i add the code in the sql can u see it plz @Tim

Comment: Don't use the sa account on production servers. Set a super complex/long password on that account, make alternatives account for your application and administrators, and then lock the sa password in a safety deposit box and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of your strings before you pass them into the SQL.  If a given value for a column exceeds the specified length, the statement will fail.

For example, `Name` is defined as a `VARCHAR(50)`, so your string in `@Name` must be less than or equal to 50 characters.  51 or more will cause the statement to fail.

A simple `if` statement will do this, e.g.:

```
if (txtName.Text.Length > 50)
{
    // throw an error, truncate the string, etc.
}
```

Again, you'll need to check each string so the length is less than or equal to the length in the DB column.

It would also be advisable to check the length of the input on the client side (via JavaScript or other methods) - that way you can provide immediate feedback to the user and they can correct it before they submit the information.

Comment: i will try this now but i try it and the data was not more than the length and it's still given me this error 
i see videos on YouTube all of them using txtBox and passed the ID then the convert it

Comment: Put a breakpoint and hit F5 and step into your code.  You need to make sure that each piece of data will fit in its intended column (the example of given in my answer is just an example).  Also, you're passing a sting in for `Date`, which is defined as a `DATE` column in the table, so the implicit conversion may be throwing an error as well.